# How to use <select> information in django form

Tags: python, django, html, forms, select

So I have my django project which includes a HTML page that shows a  list and a submit button.

I want to use the submit button to send the selected item ID to the server and than use it.

That`s my code :

```
<form>
<select>
{% for item in list %}
    <option value={{item.name}}>{{ item.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The things I want to know are :

1. What to write in the action of the form so it will only reload the page.
2. How to enter the form data into a view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in question 1.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Perhaps he means to submit the data and then reload the same page with the form on it

Answer (score -1):

As i understand, you want to take the value on your select and do something with it in the server.
I would advise you to read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-forms), as it is pretty detailed about what you need to know to work with forms. You should also read a little about [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), as you are missing a couple details.

Now, the action must point to one of your urls. Your url must be pointing to a view and in your view, if everything is ok, you should be getting a request object.

Depending on your post method, you have a python dictionary in request.GET or request.POST, filled with the values in your form.
That is assuming you are using your form created from scratch. In django you can use the Form class, which creates the html (or lets you create it, but giving you some constraints), validates the form, saves the form to a model (in the case it is a ModelForm). It is a valuable class for me and prefer it over working with raw html.

Also, assuming you haven't, i strongly advice you to go through the [getting started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/). Even if it keeps things basic, it does a good job at introducing core django modules.

Comment: Iv\`e read the documentation but I misunderstood some parts.

The action points what page to load next, but I need it to stay on the same page.

All I want is to edit my DB with the data I get but I don`t know how to send the data to a specific function in my views. If I use  a request.POST in my view how do I make sure It takes the data of the right form?

Comment: Action points to the url that can handle your request. You can redirect to another page if the form is correct, or render the same page with the form errors if it is not. You can have the same url handle your request, you just need to add the logic for it. The request.POST contains a dictionary...you can check it contains values that can only be on your form.